# Can I sync .vscode folder?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I use  cpptools extension. When I open folder in vscode, I have to copy . Vscode folder to new folder. It's a hassle. I know how to sync general setting by github, but I'm not sure it syncs .vscode folder in project directory.

So, can I load . vscode when I opened a new folder?

Comment: `.vscode` is your workspace settings, it's recommended to commit into git repo with the project, and it shouldn't be shared across projects.

Answer (score 1):

The `.vscode` folder is intended for workspace-specific things. If you have settings there that you need in multiple workspaces, I'd recommend moving them to your user settings.